# Hosting MVC6 Application in IIS as Application shows Empty page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-8

I have created Simple MVC6 application and hosted in IIS using the following steps. It's works fine when we host as website but getting empty page when we host this as application.

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#iis-server-configuration

Could anybody suggest the best option for this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when hosting my MVC6 application under default website. I resolved it using the **Route** attribute in MVC6.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("MVC6")]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }    
}
```

I used 2 routes for the action method index. First one will work if I host my application under a website. Second one will work if I host it directly in IIS.

Note: The string value provided in first route attribute may vary depending upon where your website is hosted.